# Bash Scripting with function that takes an argument

Tags: linux, bash

I need to create a function and pass an argument like

```
myfunc word_100
```

and then the output should display

```
word_101
```

Basically it should increment taking in account the delimiter. I am thinking to say put word as one variable and the number and increment the number and combine it together. But not sure how to go about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NAME=${1%_*}_
NUM=${1##*_}
echo $NAME`expr $NUM + 1`
```